# Are irreducible subrepresentations of a tensor product always generated by indecomposable vectors?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over $k$, and $V_i$ be (finite-dimensional) representations of $G$. Are the irreducible components of $\bigotimes_i V_i$ always generated by indecomposable vectors? That is, vectors of the form $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n$ where $v_i \in V_i$.

Comment: For $G = \operatorname{SL}(V)$ with $\operatorname{char} k \nmid \dim V$, you have $V \otimes V^* = W_1 \oplus W_2$, where $W_1$ is a $1$-dimensional submodule generated by $\sum_{i = 1}^n e_i \otimes e_i^*$, where $e_1$, $\ldots$, $e_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $e_1^*$, $\ldots$, $e_n^*$ is the corresponding dual basis. The summand $W_2$ is the kernel of the map $V \otimes V^* \rightarrow k$ defined by $v \otimes f \mapsto f(v)$, which is generated by $e_i \otimes e_j^*$ and $e_i \otimes e_i^* - e_j \otimes e_j^*$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: But can't we write $(e_i - e_j) \otimes (e_i^* + e_j^*) = e_i \otimes e_i^* - e_j \otimes e_j^* + e_i \otimes e_j^* - e_j \otimes e_i^*$?

Comment: Yes you are right! But $\sum_{i = 1}^n e_i \otimes e_i^*$ is not indecomposable.

Comment: Oh yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems unlikely, given that already the assertion is not literally true for the tensor product of two copies of the standard representation $V$ of $G=SL_2(\mathbb R)$. Namely, with $v$ a highest-weight vector in $V$, and $w$ a lowest-weight vector in $V$, with $Lv=w$ with lowering operator $L$, in $V\otimes V$, by Leibniz' rule,
$$
L(v\otimes w) \;=\; Lv\otimes w + v\otimes Lw
\;=\; w\otimes w + 0 \;=\; w\otimes w
$$
Thus, looking at the two weight-$0$ vectors in $V\otimes V$, neither $v\otimes w$ nor $w\otimes v$ is annihilated by the lowering operator. We know that $V\otimes V\approx {\mathrm{Sym}^2}\oplus {\mathrm{trivial}}$, and that the weight of the trivial representation is $0$. Indeed, $L(v\otimes w-w\otimes v)=0$, so $v\otimes w-w\otimes v$ is the vector generating the trivial repn inside the tensor product.

If $v\otimes w - w\otimes v$ were equal to $(av+nw)\otimes (cv+dw)$, upon multiplying out $ac=0$, so the coefficients of both $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ are $0$, and this is impossible.